# SAS MACRO error: Nesting of %IF statements in open code is not supported. %IF ignored

Tags: sas

When I execute this code, it came up with an error: *Nesting of %IF statements in open code is not supported. %IF ignored.*
The code is as follows:

```
%let Vis_Perform_Filter = VISYN^=:"Y";
data cp_ref_patient_visits;
    length CP_VISIT_PERFORMED 8.;
    set cp_ref_patient_visits;

    /* Are all visit identifiers related to actual performed visits? */
    /* if select 'Yes' */
    %IF %superQ(Vis_Perform_Filter) eq %THEN %DO;
      CP_VISIT_PERFORMED = 1; /* 1 OR 0 */
    %END;
    /* if select 'No' then apply filter condition */
    %ELSE %IF %superQ(Vis_Perform_Filter) ne %THEN %DO;
      if &Vis_Perform_Filter. then CP_VISIT_PERFORMED = 0;
      else CP_VISIT_PERFORMED = 1;
    %END;

    label CP_VISIT_ID = "Internal Visit Identifier"
          CP_VISIT_PERFORMED = "Visit Performed Flag";

    proc sort; by SUBJID CP_PATIENT CP_VISIT_ID;
run;
```

And the Error is:

```
31 %ELSE %IF %superQ(Vis_Perform_Filter) ne %THEN %DO;
ERROR: Nesting of %IF statements in open code is not supported. %IF ignored.
ERROR: Skipping to next %END statement.
```

I want to know why this error happens? How to solve this error?
Thank you for your help~

Comment: Why do you have any %IF statements in that code at all?  And if there is a need for macro logic then embed the code into a macro and then call the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2018/07/05/if-then-else-sas-programs/) reveals

%if %then %else statements are not supported in open code until SAS 9.4M5. And there are restrictions to its use.

My suggestion is to get rid of the macro functions when you are inside a data step. For example, replace

```
%IF %superQ(Vis_Perform_Filter) eq %THEN %DO;
  CP_VISIT_PERFORMED = 1; /* 1 OR 0 */
%END;
```

with

```
if VISYN ne "Y" then CP_VISIT_PERFORMED = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of filters that are specified as 'data step source code snippets' in possible macro variables, you may want to code a separate macro (`CODEGEN_flag_logic`) to examine the filters by name and determine whether or not that source code should be emitted as part of the data step.

Example:

```
%MACRO CODEGEN_flag_logic (FILTER, DEFAULT=1);
  %* FILTER is name of macro variable containing source code that is data step logical evaluation snippet;
  %if %length(&FILTER) %then 
    %if %symexist (&FILTER) %then 
      %if %length (&&&FILTER) %then
&&&FILTER;
          %else
&DEFAULT;
        %else
&DEFAULT;
      %else
&DEFAULT;
%MEND;

%let name_flag_logic = name =: "J";  /* extant source code */

data want;
  set sashelp.class;

  name_flag = %codegen_flag_logic (name_flag_logic);
  name_flag_inverse = %codegen_flag_logic (name_flag_logic, DEFAULT=0);
run;

%let name_flag_logic = ;  /* extant macro variable with no source code */

data want;
  set sashelp.class;

  name_flag = %codegen_flag_logic (name_flag_logic);
run;

%SYMDEL name_flag_logic;  /* macro variable not present in session or scope */

data want;
  set sashelp.class;

  name_flag = %codegen_flag_logic (name_flag_logic);
run;
```

There will still be problems if said filters contain invalid SAS code or deal with variables expected in the PDV that are not present.

Such as

```
/* snippet uses homeroom (which will be noted in LOG as uninitialized */
%let name_flag_logic = homeroom = 'sunny'; 

/* snippet is invalid sas code and will show ERROR in the LOG */
%let name_flag_logic = busroute one of (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably move your logic about the value of the macro variable outside of the logic of the data step to make things clearer.   Looks like when the macro variable is empty you want to execute the ELSE clause of the IF statement.  So just set the value to something that is false.

```
%let Vis_Perform_Filter = VISYN^=:"Y";
%IF %superQ(Vis_Perform_Filter) eq %THEN %DO;
  %let Vis_Perform_Filter=0;
%END;
```

Then generating your data step code does not require any macro logic, much less any nested macro logic.  You just expand the value of the macro variable where the IF statement is expecting the code to use to evaluate the condition.

```
data cp_ref_patient_visits;
    length CP_VISIT_PERFORMED 8.;
    set cp_ref_patient_visits;

    /* Are all visit identifiers related to actual performed visits? */
    if &Vis_Perform_Filter. then CP_VISIT_PERFORMED = 0;
    else CP_VISIT_PERFORMED = 1;

    label CP_VISIT_ID = "Internal Visit Identifier"
          CP_VISIT_PERFORMED = "Visit Performed Flag"
    ;
run;

proc sort; by SUBJID CP_PATIENT CP_VISIT_ID;
run;
```